# Declaration after instantiation works only if class doesn't implement interface

Tags: php

```
new A;

class A {}

new C;

class C extends A {}

new B;

class B implements iB {}
interface iB {} // we can even put interface definition after the class
                // that implements it
```

I expect this code to work without errors, while I'm getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'B' not found in ...

Could someone explain why this happens? Is it a documented behaviour?

PS: php 5.3.2

PPS: the same behaviour on ideone: http://ideone.com/q4cT6A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *as expected* in PHP. Sorry for the answer, I expected this once too. ;)

Quote from the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php):

> Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before they are used. If a class extends another, then the parent class must be declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to classes that inherit other classes and interfaces.

Comment: Everything *expected* should be documented somehow ;-)

Comment: "If a class extends another, then the parent class must be declared before the child class structure" --- and this behaves *even stranger*: http://ideone.com/ZDx0O7

Comment: hehe :) crazy example!! I would consider to report this as a bug to PHP. (And thereby adding a change request: "Functions can be used before declaration. Why classes don't behave the same? Can this be implemented?")

Comment: That won't work. Once they documented it - it will be rejected as "not a bug", proven

Comment: But the change request would being interesting. I thought 5 minutes about that....-> Currently I don't see that this should break downward compatibility or anything. (not sure at the moment) But it would be very useful and would be similar to the behaviour of functions.